# custom setter method for delegate gets called infinite times

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

In my VC I have declared a custom delegate property:

```
@interface VC2 : BaseVC
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<VC2Delegate> delegate;
@end
```

and from VC1, I'm setting this delegate:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"VC2"]) {
        self.VC2 = [segue destinationViewController];
        [self.VC2 setDelegate:self];
    }
  }
```

and in my VC2, I have written a setter method for the delegate:

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id)del{
    self.delegate=del;
}
```

The issue, after the pprepareForSegue method call in VC1, the setter method for delegate in VC2 gets called so many times and my apps get crashed. I'm not sure what could be the reason.

Here is the satcktrace:

[image]

[image]

I don't have any implementation my BaseVC. It's just a plain VC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your problem 
self.delegate is actually a setter, that is why you have cycling. 
You should use _delegate = del inside of your setter.

Answer (score 4):

When you're accessing your property with self.delegate, you're actually calling the getter. Try setting it to the instance variable as such:

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id)del{
    _delegate=del;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You not required setter method because you can directly set delegate like,

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"VC2"]) {
    self.VC2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    self.VC2.delegate = self;
}
 }
```

You just need to declare delegate property in .h file of VC2.

You can take property in VC2.h like,

```
   @property ViewController *delagate;
```

Viewconroller is you VC from wich you are calling `prepareForSegue` and setting delegate

Comment: I did this before, but the delegate became nil in VC2 after I perform some operations. So I wanted to know what is making the delegate nil. Hence I tried the setter method.

Comment: Check my update in answer

Comment: do we need the strong type for delegates ? I heard that we only shold give weak for delegates!

Comment: No need to set strong or nonautomatic!!!