# NSArray EXC BAD ACCESS under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I got a bad access problem under ARC. 
Here is the code:

**file 1**
I called the method that passes `self.array`

```
 [self.Cell setCollectionData:self.Array];
```

**file2**

in cell file, I called the following method

```
- (void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData {
    [self.subCell setCollectionData:collectionData];
}
```

**file 3**

finally, the method called

```
- (void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData {
    self.collectionData = collectionData;
}
```

Here, the `collectionData` caused a BAD ACCESS error.

However, I solved the problem by changing `self.cell` and `self.subcell` to `_cell` and `_subcell`.

My question is, why the bad access problem happened under ARC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom setter method for delegate gets called infinite times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615344/custom-setter-method-for-delegate-gets-called-infinite-times)

Answer (score 0):

You need use ivar for your setter method and also for getter,dealloc and init methods. The problem that you tired set value through value setter and as a result got infinite cycle of setts. `self.collectionData =` call this method `-(void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData` again and again , I mean. And you need use it like below

```
-(void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData { 
    _collectionData = collectionData; 
}
```